# convert character variable to numeric in oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion

I am new in oracle. I am trying to convert a character variable to numeric variable in oracle. The variable contains the 1 and 0 as a value that's why I want to convert this variable to numeric. 
I have a table like this

```
PDS(varchar2)
1
0
1
0
```

But I want like this

```
PDS(number)
1
0
1
0
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including your code so we can see what you are trying to change rather than having to guess from your brief description.

Comment: You mean `to_number()`?

Comment: Do you mean as you query the data; or you want to change the column data type in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that all rows are strictly numeric, run this alter statement.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable modify ( PDS NUMBER );
```

If it fails, follow these steps.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable  ADD (PDS_temp NUMBER);
UPDATE yourtable SET PDS_temp  = to_number(PDS);
--Dont proceed if the above statement fails.

ALTER TABLE yourtable   DROP COLUMN PDS;
ALTER TABLE yourtable  RENAME COLUMN PDS_temp TO PDS;
```

Comment: It's not working. Got error which says "column to be modified must be empty to change datatype"

Comment: @AkshayPatil : Modified.Take a look

Comment: In a simplified wold, temporary column option would work. If PDS column was involved in indexes or constraints, that might cause a headache to someone. I'm not saying that this is a *wrong* way - it just might need some *improvement* if it turns out that the world is bigger than a nutshell. For a newbie, it is most probably not.

Comment: @Littlefoot : Agreed

Comment: @AkshayPatil : Although it solved your problem, you must understand fully the consequences of performing such changes, as littlefoot clearly mentioned. It is reasonable to assume that you are using a test environment on this occasion. But, always keep in mind that dropping a column should be attempted only if you have taken into consideration the indexes, partitions and dependent programs (packages,procedures etc). I am sure they would follow best practices in your workplace to avoid such incidents, but who knows? . Anyways, wish you all the best .

Comment: @KaushikNayak Actually I have to use this table in my environment i.e. SAS so I really dont know anything about these consequences in oracle. Thanks for your information. Its very easy to convert one datatype into another in SAS but we got this data in oracle environment so we r supposed to work in oracle environment only.